# Trivial question in Laurent product sums.

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume we have Laurent Series:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k x^k , \ \sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} b_k x^k $$

And I multiply them together, the coeffecient will be the convolution of $a_k$ and $b_k$ but I am not sure I see what are the boundaries of this convolution, is it from $-n-1$ upto $n$ or something else?

Just the boundaries make me unsettled.

Comment: In general, it's from $-\infty$ to $\infty$: $(\sum a_k x^k)(\sum b_\ell x^\ell)=\sum_m (\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_j b_{m-j}) x^m$.

Comment: OK, thanks. You can terminate this post.

Answer (score 1):

As David Moews said,  the coefficient of $x^m$ in the product is $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_j b_{m-j}$. The convergence of this series is not guaranteed: thus, multiplication of two Laurent series may fail to exist even formally (in the sense of having well-defined coefficients). In the special case of one-sided series (e.g. $a_j=0=b_j$ for $j<-N$) this issue does not appear, because the sum defining the coefficients becomes finite.